# How to run this node app that I imported from github?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web, server

First off, I am a complete noob to web development involving servers. I've searched tirelessly and done everything within my knowledge. I am way too curious to figure out how to run this node js app. Is it possible for anyone to give me a step by step instructions on how to get it running?

https://github.com/android-fanatic/video-timeline-comment-tagging-demo

I have mongodb and nodejs installed but I get this Darwin Error when I run

```
npm start

npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/JonDoe/Documents/web_apps/video-timeline-comment-ta`
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: npm start? I see no reference to that in the instructions, perhaps read the instructions

Answer (score 1):

Inside the package.json file, the start script is not specified, so `npm start` wont work. Change your package.json to the following

```
    {
    "name":"real-video-fake-tags",
    "version":"0.0.4",
    "private":true,
    "scripts": {
       "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "dependencies":{
        "express":"2.5.10",
        "jade":">= 0.2.0",
        "mongoose" :">= 2.7.0",
        "mailer":">=0.6.7"
    }
    }
```

Comment: `    npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! real-video-fake-tags@0.0.4 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the real-video-fake-tags@0.0.4 start script 'node app.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the real-video-fake-tags package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.`

That is the error I got after doing that :(

Comment: What happens when you enter `node app.js` instead of `npm start` ?

Comment: Moreover, installation guide in README.md of that repo gives some nice advice there as well: `run 'app.js' and have fun`, which means what Bidhan said.

Comment: @alex @bidhan I get a different error now :/
`Express server listening on port 4444 in development mode

/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/web_apps/video-timeline-comment-tagging-demo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)`

Comment: Is your mongodb instance up and running?

Comment: Yea, I got it to run, but I get this error:

`Express
500 Error: /Users/JohnDoe/Documents/web_apps/video-timeline-comment-tagging-demo/views/layout.jade:1 > 1| !!! 2| html 3| head 4| title= title `!!!` is deprecated, you must now use `doctype`
> 1| !!!
2| html
3| head
4| title= title
`!!!` is deprecated, you must now use `doctype``